# PostgreSQL Citus Extension Temp Table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-extensions, citus

Is it possible with citus extension in PostgreSQL to create temp table that is copied to each worker node (like reference table)?

When I run SQL like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mypoint; 
CREATE TEMP TABLE mypoint (mpoint geometry primary key); 
SELECT create_reference_table('mypoint');
```

I get the error:

> ```
> ERROR:  unacceptable schema name "pg_temp_6"
> DETAIL:  The prefix "pg_" is reserved for system schemas.
> CONTEXT:  while executing command on mynode01:5432 SQL state: 42939
> ```

The reason I am asking this is because there are more SQL commands afterwards where I need to do a join between the temp table and a distributed table (which is not allowed with citus extension).

Comment: All postgresql temporary tables, are maked in a system schema named pg_temp, its look like your extension, just try to rename the schema to pg_temp_6, so it looks like not compatible.... Because as the error says prefix pg_ are reserved for system schemas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it is not possible to create reference nor distribute temp table to worker nodes as of citus 7.3.

There are two possible workarounds:

1. Modify your queries to avoid joins between the temp table and the distributed table (see [SQL workarounds](http://citus-docs.readthedocs.io/en/v7.3/reference/sql_workarounds.html))
2. Create temp table as regular table and then mark it as reference table before populating

Since I needed sub-second queries for user response the first option worked better for me.

Here is an example of how I modified a query:

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myresult1;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE myresult1 AS 
    select mpoint, mgrsid, st_distance(mgrspoint, mpoint) as distance from fact_point_kpi
    inner join mypoint on st_dwithin(mgrspoint, mpoint, 0.001)
    ORDER BY mpoint, distance;

--becomes =>

    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS myresult1;
    CREATE TEMP TABLE myresult1 AS 
    SELECT mpoint, mgrsid, st_distance(mgrspoint, mpoint) AS distance
    FROM (SELECT mpoint FROM mypoint) AS mptmp
    JOIN fact_point_kpi ON st_dwithin(mgrspoint, mptmp.mpoint, 0.001)
    ORDER BY mptmp.mpoint, distance;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example the temp table is created in schema `pg_temp_6`. `create_reference_table` tries to create the exact same schema in the worker, and fails.

Could you just create a regular reference table, and drop it when you are done instead of creating a temporary table ?

Comment: Creating regular reference table would probably be too slow for query that has to run under a second. However, I have managed to restructure my queries and will write an answer based on that. Thanks for help!